# Как добавить в Chrome extension доп функции

Tags: chrome-extension

Сделал простое приложение для хрома которое выводит popup, но мне необходимо добавить параметры для приложения. Как это сделать? Где хранить данные? Так же интересует вопрос как с помощью расширения менять информацию на сайте а не в popup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Храните где удобнее, зависит от типа приложения:

Много табличных данных - indexedDb или Web SQL.

Если мало данных - можно в localStorage.

Менять информацию можно инъекцией js в страницу. [content_scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) или [chrome.tabs.executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript).

Comment: Можно ли как то брать сайты для инъекций из localstorage?

Comment: и возможно если знаете напишите где можно взять более подробную информацию как менять контент через эти инъекции)

Comment: Можно, но для списка лучше база данных. Но можно массив сайтов в `json` хранить как `string` и в `localStorage`. Менять контент абсолютно так-же как и на своём сайте.

Comment: как тогда можно получить local storage на инжект скрипте? localstorage который я сохранил в option.html ..